# Chef cookbook version delete, or update specific version

Tags: version, chef-infra, knife, cookbook

I have long history of a cookbook that has a recipe of the app and is constantly modified. It got to the point where cookbook version is 226. I'm wondering how can upload files to specific cookbook version. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

when you run `knife cookbook upload` it will update whatever version is listed in your local `metadata.rb` file.  (unless it is frozen).  If you use Berks, you'll need to add the `--force` option to overwrite an existing version.

deleting a specific version is as easy as `knife cookbook delete mycookbook 1.4.3`